# Slow incoming mail flow after backpressure situation

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange, exchange-2010

Me and my supervisor have been bashing our heads against the wall the past week trying to figure out why our Exchange server is going through the queue incredibly slowly. This all started after a backpressure situation caused by logs filling their assigned disk.

Stats on the server:
Exchange 2010 running on Windows Server 2012 R2 in a Hybrid configuration with Office 365
16 logical cores, box is sitting around 1-5% CPU usage
72GB of ram in the box, of which 78% is used at any given time
Exchange is installed on a drive with a capacity of 205GB, of which 77GB are free
The main database is on a drive with a capacity of 2TB, of which 338GB are free
The main logs are on a drive with a capacity of 929GB, of which 261GB are free

Mail flow order:

1. Into and out of an onsite Barracuda Spam Filter, this happens almost instantly
2. Into Exchange itself, this is fairly quick
3. Out of Exchange, this takes anywhere from 15 to 20 minutes, can be longer depending on queue
4. Into and out of the onsite Barracuda Spam Filter again, once again, nearly instant
5. Into Office 365, this is really fast as well
6. Finally, delivered to the users' Outlook client

The message queue fills up over the course of the day, it's processing it slower than new emails come in. It *was* performing just fine before the backpressure that happened around a week ago, and we even tried disabling backpressure to see if that fixed it, no dice.

Any ideas what could be causing this, and what steps we should take to resolve this issue?

We've tried rebuilding transport logs to no avail. The server seems to think there's backpressure but there's no indication that there actually is

Comment: Have you verified all the monitored resources?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/back-pressure?view=exchserver-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is flowing faster now, disabling virus scanning in the spam filter sped everything back up. New virus definitions caused it to slow everything down.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing:) Glad to you have found the rooted cause, you could mark your reply as best answer if someone encounters the same issue, he/she can find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 0):

What are specific error messages in event logs? Have you Identified the resources which trigger the back pressure mechanism and take actions to make more of them available?

In addition, try to modify the back pressure thresholds, allowing the continued operation of the Exchange server within the same environment and check if this issue continues.

For more details: [Understanding Back Pressure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010/bb201658(v=exchg.141)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Another way is to restart transport service and check again.